# What is the best way to reserve a cluster node without submitting a job right away?

Tags: cluster-computing, pbs, qsub

I need to reserve a node, then interactively log in and do something, log out and have the reservation expire after N minutes (not right after I log out as it happens when I do this with qlogin). I'm typically using qsub to submit jobs on this cluster.

Comment: What scheduler are you using? The solution depends on your scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

With a scheduler like Moab or Maui, you can create a reservation on the node (or have the administrator do it).

Or, you can submit a single-core job to a node with the SINGLEUSER node access policy, specifying a longer wall time than your interactive sessions will last. You can then submit your interactive jobs to that same node with `-l nodes=<host>`.

Finally (and I apologize in advance if this seems like a dumb response): you could just stay logged in to your interactive session, and come back to it when you're done....